# Java - cant deserialize xml

Tags: java, xml, jackson

Cant wrap my head around this.
This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <username>Tom</username>
        <password>123</password>
    </user>
    <user>
        <username>Moc</username>
        <password>1234</password>
    </user>
</users>
```

And these are my classes in Java:

Users.java

```
@Data
public class Users {
    private List<User> user;
}
```

User.java

```
@Data
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

For some reason I am constantly getting error:
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "user"

My loading method is here:

```
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Users.xml").getFile());
            String xmlContent = XMLReader(new FileInputStream(file));
            XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            Users users = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlContent, Users.class);
```

XMLReader is just method which reads xml file line by line.
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

1. You are trying to parse the `Users` class using a `<users>` tag (lowercase). This will not work **unless** you annotate the class with `@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "users")`
2. in the line `String xmlContent = XMLReader(new FileInputStream(file))` I don't know what `XMLReader` is (maybe a misnamed method), anyway you don't need to load your entire xml in a string in memory, this is inefficient, just pass to `readValue()` you file's inputstream.
3. By default Jackson tries to create a wrapper element for the lists, so it expect your xml to have this structure:

```
<users>
  <user>   <--- this is the list element wrapper
    <user>   <--- this is the actual "user"
      <username>
      <password>
    </user>
  </user>
</users>
```

If you want to avoid the wrapper, you have to annotate the `user` list with `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)`

Below a working example for class `Users` working for your xml example

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "users")
@Data
public class Users {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<User> user;
}
```

And this is a working snippet to parse the file:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Users.xml").getFile());
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
Users users = xmlMapper.readValue(new FileInputStream(file), Users.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for brief explanation. I tried to use your code but now im getting this : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "username" (class com.pai.project.paiProject.bootstrap.User), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (FileInputStream); line: 4, column: 33] (through reference chain: com.pai.project.paiProject.bootstrap.Users["user"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.pai.project.paiProject.bootstrap.User["username"])

Comment: Are you sure Lombok is working correctly? Try to manually add getters and setters for the 'username' and 'password' fields in the User class and get rid of the @Data annotation

Comment: Seems like you're right. Im so confused because sometimes it worked correctly some time ago and now intellijj is making jokes on me. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: I deeply hate Lombok, but I know it's very popular these times...